# Is it the best option to convert a java interface with static fields in a abstract class in c#?

Tags: java, c#, interface, field, abstract-class

```
public interface IHashStorage<T> {
    public static final float INITIAL_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.7f;
    public static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 149;
}
```

I have the code above which needs to be translated in c#. The only solution that seems to be proper is to make it an abstract class.From what I found it's safer to use readonly than const:

```
public abstract class IHashStorage<T>
    {
        private readonly float INITIAL_LOAD_FACTOR = (float)0.7;

        private readonly int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 149;
    }
```

The project in Java is using the Decorator pattern and Proxy, the transformation from java to c# can possibly require to use more abstract classes(currently in java there are only interfaces used)?I know theoretically the difference between them but practically in c# I used abstract classes more.I'm not that familiar with java and I would like to know your advice about how to find the best solution to finish this task, I mean the main points to keep in mind when converting the code.

Comment: As an aside, it seems wrong to have the fields that you mention attached to an interface (which is kind of why it isn't allowed in C#).  Interfaces should not define implementation, and load factors and initial capacities are implementation details.  Those should be left to a specific implementation of the interface, not the interface itself.

Comment: Small note, no need to cast to float when you assign.  You can still use 0.7f;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define an interface with a get property.

 then, make my base class implement it and set the default values

 and then, extend the base class for every java class that implements the java interface.

 something along these lines:

```
public interface IHashStorage<T>
{
    float InitialLoadFactor { get; }
    int InitialCapacity { get; }
}

public class HashStorageBase<T> : IHashStorage<T>
{
    private readonly float _initialLoadFactor = 0.7f;
    private readonly int _initialCapacity = 149;
    public float InitialLoadFactor
    {
        get { return _initialLoadFactor; }
    }

    public int InitialCapacity
    {
        get { return _initialCapacity; }
    }
}

public class HashStorage1<T> : HashStorageBase<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I imply in my comment, there is no way to attach fields (or any other implementation details) to an interface in C#.  You have two options besides making this an abstract class:

1. Make the fields into (probably read-only) properties on the interface, which will force all implementations to specify them.
2. Make the fields into custom attributes defined on the interface and/or the implementions.